# Laravel Cache: how do identify what writes data to it

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Recently, in one of our projects that use Laravel 5.4, we have noticed that some data is being cached in `/storage/framework/cache/data` - we are using file cache. The contents of the files in the cache are things like: `1529533237i:1;`. Several files are created in the cache throughout the day with content similar to that. So many files are created that we have to clean this cache periodically in order not to run into disk space issues by running out of inodes.

I know that an alternative to using file cache are things like Redis or Memcache, but the issue is, we're not sure what is this data being cached or what component of the project is caching it. We do use several external libraries so it could be one of many, but we don't know for sure what. I've already looked into all configuration files of the project, but couldn't identify anything that is obviously controlling data caching.

Are there any recommendations on trying to identify which piece of code is writing this data so we can better handle the caching of this data, whatever it may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has several [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache#events) that dispatch during caching.

Create a new listener that listens on the `Illuminate\Cache\Events\KeyWritten` event.  You could log the backtrace to see exactly what leads to specific items being cached.